# How to hide ASP.NET webservice methods?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7, asmx

We have these SOAP methods running on a single .asmx URL. But we would like to hide some methods from a given user. We have 2 users, each one shouldn't see the methods used by the other.

I think we need to separate the methods in different URLs, but maybe it isn't enough. Should we use separate projects? Is there any ASP.NET or IIS feature that allows us to do it easily?

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? Make the service less-discoverable? It sounds more like you want some form of access-control.

Comment: why dont you use security in the headers ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir how does that work? does it requires credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't hide Web methods. Webservice public method marked with WebServiceAttribute attribute will be exposed.

Answer (score 0):

> To hide webmethods, maybe there is a workround can help you:
>
> Build an ashx file to call webservice on server-side, and access this
> ashx file to retrieve the result from client-side by using
> XMLHttpRequest. ashx page is an agent page to access the web service
> and get the result from web method. The client can use XMLHttpRequest
> to get the result from ashx page. With this appraoch, the client side
> is not able to get know what's the web method, just know ashx url

#### [Source: ASP.NET Forum - Vince Xu](http://forums.asp.net/t/1478149.aspx)